# What is the benefit of creating an extra div container when using React Portals?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to understand React **Portals**, so I looked to the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html#usage).

I still don't understand why in their examples (https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/yzMaBd and https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html#event-bubbling-through-portals) they are creating an extra div in the constructor and passing it to the second argument of the `createPortal` function.

Why don't they use directly the `modalRoot` container like this ?

```
const modalRoot = document.getElementById('modal-root');

class Modal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
      this.props.children,
      modalRoot,
    );
  }
}
```

In the codepen example, the explanation is given by this comment

> Create a div that we'll render the modal into. Because each Modal component has its own element, we can render multiple modal components into the modal container.

In this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wgnthp) example, I tried to render multiple components into the portal container **without using an extra div** and it seems to work perfectly, `React.createPortal` already appends the child to container, and when the component is unmount, it only removes the child from the container and doesn't clear all the container's content, so we don't have to do this manually. Am I missing something ?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong without using `<div />` wrapper. Does the docs say so somewhere?

Comment: https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/yzMaBd look at the comment in the constructor, they say they are creating a div to be able to render multiple modal components into the modal container. But it's seemed to be already possible without creating an extra div

Comment: Is that because fragments are not possible in this case? I played with the sandbox and it seemed like so

Comment: I don't think it's compulsory though. Been using material-ui and have never seen they put an extra div

Comment: I updated my example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-wgnthp?file=PortalComponent.jsx with fragments, it seems to work well. If it's not necessary, I don't understand why they show it in their example because it can generate some problems when `a child component requires to be attached to the DOM tree immediately when mounted`

Comment: Hmm fair enough. I really don't see a problem tbh

Comment: I am also confused. But I am thinking that it eases the unmounting of the newly created element. While showing Modal, we will appendChild at #modal, and while unmounting, we just need to remove the child from DOM using removeChild to prevent memory leaks.